# As the author of content, is there a way to view content as a read-only user will see it?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, view, read-only

I am creating pages for a new site, and want to get a sense of what the site contents will look like to a read-only user.  In other words I want a way to hide all the features that I am seeing as site author and owner such as edit options, etc.

As I am on a corporate network with corporate logins, I can't create a second account to test the read-only view.

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, when you as a site owner, there's no option to view contents as a read-only user.